# What are the ramifications of non-final resource IDs in Android Gradle Plugin version 5.0 for Android Annotations?

Tags: android-annotations

Android Annotations relies heavily on resource IDs as annotation attributes. With each such attribute in code, the latest Android Studio issues a warning saying "Resource IDs will be non-final in Android Gradle Plugin version 5.0, avoid using them as annotation attributes". I know that ButterKnife worked around the problem by generating R2.java that consists all resource IDs from R.java declared as final. What's the suggested solution for Android Annotations?

Comment: This was already the issue with library modules, you van apply the same for your app. https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Library-projects